# Error on Installing Docker: Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, wsl-2

I'm having a Windows VM running Windows 10 Pro and I'm trying to install Docker running with WSL2.

However, the I'm bumping into the error below and I can confirm that **Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature** is already enabled.

[image]

Comment: Are you installing on VMWare?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error and followed these steps for VMWare,

- Go to VM Settings >> Hardware >> Processors
- In the Virtualization Engine Box, select the checkbox 'virtualize intel vt-x/ept or amd-v/rvi'
- Restart your VM

Comment: thanks for your help! Unfortunately, it's not on VMWare.